# Laravel [5.3] Polymorphic Relation using whereHas return column not found

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3, laravel-query-builder

- Laravel Version: 5.3.9
- PHP Version: 7
- Database Driver & Version: MariaDB 10

My current model structure:

```
   Image.php

public function imageable()
    {
        return $this->morphTo();
    }

User.php

public function images()
    {
        return $this->morphMany(Image::class, 'imageable');
    }
```

#### Steps To Reproduce:

I query it like this:

```
    $gender = 1;
$lookIds = Image::whereHas('imageable' , function($query) use($gender){
            $query->where('gender', $gender);
        })->get();
```

It return me:

`SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'gender' in 'where clause`

Any suggestion or better solution to get all Image within user with gender 0?

Answer (score 0):

try using this:

```
 $gender = 1;
 $lookIds = Image::whereHas('users', function($query) use ($gender) {
     $query->where('gender',$gender);
 })->get();
```

I am assuming your user table has a gender field?

Comment: `Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::users()` I've tried your code it return error. thanks

Comment: Why don't you have a reverse relationship on your Image.php for users?  That would make the code work.. Try adding the relationship.

Comment: I'm using polymorphic relationship so I don't have any user_id field for it.  and my basic code is from laravel 5.3 documentation. Is it best practice having 2 relationship like that?. thanks.

Comment: Or you could do $users = User::where('gender', $gender)->get(); and then do a foreach ($users as $user) { array_push($lookIds, $user->images()->get()->lists('id')->toArray();}